# How to handle application shutdown in Quartz.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, quartz.net

I have used Quartz.Net for queuing and sending emails from my application. I don't know how each scheduled job responds to application instance stopping, pausing or shutting down. The IJob interface has no method that can notify a running job about these events.

My question is how can I handle these cases when they occur so that the job can exit while leaving the application and the data in a stable state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you call `IScheduler.Shutdown(true)` when your application shuts down. This will wait for all jobs to finish and ensure everything is cleaned up correctly.

Comment: Caution: Runtime will only wait for 90 seconds, after that worker process will be terminated. That means jobs running more than 90 seconds after a call to `IScheduler.Shutdown(true)` will be  unexpectedly terminated by runtime.